# What does Loki say at the end of Season 2, Episode 4?

Tags: the-almighty-johnsons

In The Almighty Johnsons, what did Loki say to Ty at the end of Season 2, Episode 4, as they stood in front of Eva/Hel's pyre?  I haven't been able to make it out, and given Loki's threats suspect it may be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loki says "You'll keep." Loki does not seem too angry or threatening when he says that.